# Why do settings disappear? Mail, usuallly

Tags: email, password, settings

Long-time Mac user, curious why, from time to time, Mail settings just plain disappear.

I only discover this when Mail suddenly can't connect. Have to input passwords again.

And not the same password or place (several email accounts.) Could be the server p/w missing, or the POP3. One of life's little mysteries, has persisted since at least Lion.

The keychain entries are fine, the keychain and in fact whole system well-maintained. So where do they go? What erases them and why?

Comment: It will do that once per year !

Comment: Oops, should I confess to duping my own question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation from my provider's tech support:

> We think you should turn off [automatically manage connection
>   settings]; there should never be any reason for it to use different
>   ones. You always want it to stick with the recommended port 587
>   (etc.), no matter what.
>
> The trouble with that feature is that if your ISP connection stops
>   working for a second, and Apple Mail can't connect, it will think "oh,
>   the settings might be wrong, so let's try a different port". It tries
>   something else at random, and maybe it works, because your ISP
>   connection is working again. But Apple Mail wrongly assumes the port
>   setting was the trouble -- so it saves the new setting! And then
>   you're using something weird that only works on certain networks,
>   etc., when it would have been better to keep the original "works
>   everywhere" port number.
>
> Apple Mail is the only program we know of that does anything like
>   this, and it's not a good idea, really; it's designed to help people
>   if their mail server company changes things, but can cause problems in
>   other cases. We've even seen cases where it randomly changes the
>   settings to something that can never possibly work on any servers,
>   although it's not supposed to.

As evidence for this explanation, when I turned it off and it revealed the port settings, they were different for each account (but all were wrong).